# Getting CUDA out of memory error on Google Colab when there is enough free memory

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I am getting a CUDA out of memory error on Google Colab when there is enough free memory

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 14.96 GiB already allocated; 21.75 MiB free; 14.98 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I am using a batch size of 1 and I have emptied cache using `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`. Anyone have any ideas of what could be happening?

Comment: Its probably memory fragmentation, being so close to the limit of maximum GPU memory usage will probably also mean there is enough RAM, but its fragmented so there is actually no contiguous block of the required size. Just try to use less RAM or get a GPU with more RAM.